# No puedo almacenar imágenes en mi Firebase (Android Studio) -Error = W/DynamiteModule: Failed to retrieve remote module version

Tags: java, android, firebase

Buenos días, soy nuevo aquí al menos en la parte en español pero preferí mudarme para acá, esta es mi primera pregunta (soy nuevo programando llevo como poco más de un par de semanas). Estoy siguiendo una serie de tutoriales para hacer una aplicación en Android tipo Blog usando Firebase. El error sucede cuando en la pantalla de enviar la imagen a mi storage en Firebase luego de seleccionarla de mi galería y hacer clic en botón que en teoría debería enviarla a almacenar además de haber llenado los campos para asignarle un título y descripción la pantalla del emulador solo me muestra el toast "Posting to Blog..." que le asigné que mostrara, pero este se queda allí indefinidamente, se mantiene eternamente cargando y nunca se cierra. Además de que la imagen no se almacena. He cambiado las regla de mi Firebase tanto en Storage como en Database a públicas siguiendo las reglas de https://firebase.google.com/docs/ he agregado premisos a Internet en el Manifest y he cambiado en gradle build la versión de los servicios de 10.0.0 a 9.6.0 pero igualmente.

Este es el tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0ScnHJi8WY&t son solo 8 minutos.

La consolar al correr la aplicación en el emulador me muestra los siguientes errores

```
 W/DynamiteModule: Failed to retrieve remote module version.
 W/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module via fast   routecom.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zza: Failed to connect to   dynamite module ContentResolver.
 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 9877470
 W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage not found.
 I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module  com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0 and remote module   com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0
  E/NetworkRqFactoryProxy: NetworkRequestFactoryProxy failed with a RemoteException:
                         com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.zzj(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzaaN(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzaba(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                             at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/UploadTask: Unable to create a network request from metadata
               android.os.RemoteException
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.<init>(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.zzj(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzaaN(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzaba(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                  at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                  at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: null
                    android.os.RemoteException
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.<init>(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.zzj(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzaaN(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzaba(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                        at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                        at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: null
                    android.os.RemoteException
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.<init>(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.zzj(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzaaN(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzaba(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                        at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                        at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/EGL_emulation: tid 2710: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x8b8cd120, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
```

Este es mi build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.social.socialpart.socialpart"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',         {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.1.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Y por ultimo mi clase en java, espero alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias,

```
 public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton mSlectImage;
private EditText mPostTittle;
private EditText mPostDesc;

private Button SubmitButton;
private Uri mImageUri= null;

private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST=1;
private StorageReference mStorage;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    mStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    mPostTittle=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.CreatePost_title);
    mPostDesc=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.CreatePost_description);
    SubmitButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Publicar_button);
    mProgress=new ProgressDialog(this);

    mSlectImage=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    mSlectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });
    SubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startPosting();
        }
    });
}

private void startPosting() {

    mProgress.setMessage("Posting to Blog...");
    mProgress.show();

    String title_val= mPostTittle.getText().toString().trim();
    String desc_val= mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val)&& mImageUri!=null){
        StorageReference filepath=mStorage.child("Blog_images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

        filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    if (requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        mImageUri=data.getData();
        mSlectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: acá hablan de 2 soluciones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328890/android-firebase-dynamitemodule-failed-to-load-module-descriptor

Comment: Puse las bases de datos de storage como públicas de nuevo y de esa pregunta me funcionó colocar los métodos de autenticación como anónimos, pero esto me generó un nuevo error, que solucioné bajando de nuevo las Firebase/Play Services Version a 9.6.0 pero esta vez aquí https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android encontré la versión de las UI de Firebase que le corresponde a las 9.6.0 que son los firebase UI 0.6.0, ya que la consola no me corre 10.0.1 y esto me funcionó. Gracias eso me dio una idea de como solucionar todo.

Comment: @Maguz si gustas, puedes componer una respuesta citando las fuentes que mencionas en tu comentario, con esto, le das mas visibilidad a tu respuesta; además de que los comentarios son temporales.

Comment: @Mauricio no entendí bien, que respuesta de la url le solucionó, sí tu lo entendiste por favor agrega la respuesta tú, yo no me molesto mientras ayude a alguien más

Comment: me ocurria lo mismo, aveces la version del firebase hay que tocarlas un poco en el gradle, aveces poniendo la ultima, o aveces poniendo unas anteriores, la verdad es algo que deberian de arreglar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dice en la documentacion de [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android), dice que debes configurar la versión con respecto a la versión utilizada para firebase.

```
FirebaseUI Version  Firebase/Play Services Version
          1.1.1     10.0.0 or 10.0.1
          1.0.1     10.0.0 or 10.0.1
          1.0.0     9.8.0
          0.6.2     9.8.0
          0.6.1     9.6.1
          0.6.0     9.6.0
          0.5.3     9.4.0
          0.4.4     9.4.0
          0.4.3     9.2.1
          0.4.2     9.2.0
          0.4.1     9.0.2
          0.4.0     9.0.0
```

Y viendo tu **build.gradle** estas usando otra versión lo cual no encaja con tu versión de firebase.

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.1.1'
```

**Debería de ser así**

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
```

**Nota** Ahi en tu log bien dice que la version del play services no es compatible con la que estas compilando

```
Requires 10084000 but found 9877470
```

Comment: Si, eso fue lo que había notado y arriba comenté que logré solucionarlo así, pero elijo tu respuesta ya que para futuras búsquedas de otros usuarios está muy completa y debe resolver futuras dudas. Gracias.